# I have to fetch checked value of radiobox in ng repeat whose value is dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to fetch the value of a checked radio button by using foreach, but it shows undefine.

The code looks like this:

```
           <form name="exitEmp" ng-submit=submit(exitEmp) novalidate>

                    <table>

                        <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <br />

                            <th>Factors</th>
                            <th>Poor</th>
                            <th>Average</th>
                            <th>Above Average</th>
                            <th>Good</th>
                 <th>Excellent</th>                                                         </tr>
                 <div >
               <div>
             <tr ng-if="feedback.qtype=='radio'" ng-repeat="feedback in empratingquestion" >

                                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                                      <td>{{feedback.question}}</td>
                                        <td><input type="radio"  value={{feedback.value}} ng-model="feedback.value.selected"></td>
                                                                    <td><input type="radio" ></td>
                                                                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                                                                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                                                                    <td><input type="radio"></td>

                                                                </tr>

                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </table>



                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                                    <div class="center">
                                                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
```

**here is controller:**

```
$scope.selectedItems=[];
$scope.submit=function(form) {
    angular.forEach($scope.empratingquestion,function(feedback){
        if(feedback.value.selected){        
            $scope.selectedItems.push(feedback.value);          
        }
    })
    alert($scope.selectedItems)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show **empratingquestion** object.. Put your code in jsfiddle or some other. 
try this..

```
<label class="radio-button" ng-repeat="feedback in empratingquestion">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="feedback.name" name="evaluatorOptions" ng-value="{{feedback.name}}">{{feedback.name}}
        </label>
```